# How can I do "presets" in Django models

Tags: django

I create a store of products.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u'name'), max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_(u'quantity'))

>>> Product.objects.create(name="egg", quantity="100")
>>> Product.objects.create(name="ham", quantity="10")
```

Now I want to create recipes, something like: scrambled eggs from 3 eggs and one piece of ham.
I tried to describe something like:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(u'name'), max_length=200)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name='recipe_sets')
```

But stuck in the description the number of the required products for one `recipe`.

Should I put the `quantity` in an other model? How can I calculate the number of servings (depending on quantity of product)? Is there an elegant way or application for a deduction of products (as a result of cooking one dish)?

Comment: This isn't really a django question. This is a schema design question. You should probably do some research on schema design for an Order/Product/Parts type application of which there are many. This will get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need another table. `ManyToMany` will create an intermediate table linking the two models you have. But if you're more explicit in how that table is created, you can add fields onto the linking table.

See the documentation [extra fields on many to many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Basically, you'd have another model:

```
class Ingredients(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    quantity = models.SomeField(..)
```

And then change your `Recipe` definition for the `ManyToManyField`:

```
items = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name='recipe_sets', through='Ingredients')
```